# How to Make my Editing Software Display Images at the Same Size as the Web?

Tags: resize, dpi, monitor

I bought a new high DPI Microsoft Surface with 216 DPI, and the images are too small on the screen! I need to upload screenshots that are 550 px. But while editing/resizing/cropping them in MSPaint, they look much smaller than they do in the browser. I can't read anything

Here's what a 640px wide image looks when I open it in my browser:

[image: browser]

Here's what it looks like when I open it in MSPaint:

[image: MSPAINT]

I want to see the same size in my image editing software that I see on the web. On my old laptop, this was fine.

And if I crop by inches in MSPaint, then 5.73 inches is no longer 550px as it was in my old laptop. How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you have some system zoom applied, which is scaling the image in your browser. Go into your Windows Display settings, and set the zoom to 100%.

Comment: If I go to Windows Display settings and set the zoom to 100%, I literally can't read anything anymore! It goes from this:
https://i.imgur.com/qhI77SO.jpg

to this:

https://i.imgur.com/ckMdPs0.jpg

I know I'm old at 36, but I don't want to wear glasses just yet :P

Comment: Well if you leave the system zoom on, it will rescale images in your browser. So, you have a choice to make I think, either get glasses or just ignore the rescaling in your browser.  I'm 51. If you're old at thirty six, then I must be positively decrepit! I've used glasses for distance vision since age 18.  No one is too old for glasses if you need them!

Comment: Oh, just one more note, most browsers allow you to scale a page if you click CTRL++ or some other shortcut.

Comment: @BillyKerr No, this is REALLY small. Unusably small. Ant size small. I mean, there isn't any reason I would deliberately subject myself to such a small font. My latest eye exams show me with 20/20 vision, so I'm pretty normal. Why wear glasses when there's nothing wrong with me, just because my display chooses some ridiculously small size! I'm actually happy with how it displays in the browser. It's the rest of my system that displays it too small.

Comment: Yes I admit it does appear to be very small. I just checked that site on my laptop. I have a 4k monitor and that site is no where near as small as that when system zoom is set to 100%.  Perhaps something is up with your browser. Do you have zooming set somewhere in your browsers settings?

Comment: No, my browser zoom is normal. The problem is that the latest Microsoft Surface tablets have a "high DPI" display that shrinks everything on the screen. The only place where I can view images normally is inside the browser. The browser is the only thing that displays fine!